# what does this javascript multiple variable assignement (not really variable assignment) syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, continue

I found this example of how to shuffle an array, however I haven't ever seen a variable in javascript signed multiple values. I tried doing it in the console but it creates an error, is this not assigning multiple values, but doing something else? The function seems to be working fine so I'm not sure how to interpret this.

```
    let num=3,4,5; //returns error as expected

    Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
         var i = this.length, j, temp;//What???,its only a single variable
         if ( i == 0 ) return this;
         while ( --i ) {
             j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
             temp = this[i];
             this[i] = this[j];
             this[j] = temp;
          }
         return this;
     }
```

Comment: Please see this [to understand let and var](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-declare-variables-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

> What???,its only a single variable

No, it's declaring three variables:

- `i`, which it initializes to `this.length`
- `j`, which it doesn't initialize
- `temp`, which it doesn't initialize

...exactly as though the code were:

```
var i = this.length;
var j;
var temp;
```

The difference between `var i = this.length, j, temp;` and your `let num=3,4,5;` (other than `var` vs. `let`) is that `4` and `5` aren't valid identifier names, so you can't declare variables with those names.

More on MDN: [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: but there's an equal sign "=". Normally wouldn't you declare those variables  like this let i, j,temp;    let len=this.length;

Answer (score 0):

1. if you're want assign an array to a variable you should declare it as array: `var num=[3,4,5];`
2. `var i = this.length, j, temp;` this line means declaring variables, for first of them value assigned, for others not
3. `Array.prototype.shuffle = function()` first line of the script means that this code assigned to a class (prototype of) array, so if you want to run this you just need call it from variable `num.shuffle()`
4. correctly working example:

   ```
   var num=[3,4,5]; 

   Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
        var i = this.length, j, temp;
        if ( i == 0 ) return this;
        while ( --i ) {
            j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
            temp = this[i];
            this[i] = this[j];
            this[j] = temp;
         }
        return this;
    }
    num.shuffle()
   ```

Comment: var is in most cases obsolete as it only scopes to functions. es6 introduced let and const, which scope to all blocks of code, which includes functions like var but also loops and conditional statements